# Angular ngSwitch hiding label element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some AngularJS code to dynamically create form elements based on an array with form details (input type, value, etc.)

Here's the example code I have for a text input:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in input_array">
  <div ng-switch on="input.input_type">
    <div ng-switch-when="text">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Hello World">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the top-level `div` is repeated for every form element in the array.  The problem, is that when `input.input_type` equals "text", it doesn't show **unless** I remove the `label` tags!  I've tried doing `label` tags without any attributes (`<label>...</label>`) and it still doesn't show the input unless I remove them.

This is pretty strange, does anyone have any ideas why it would do that?  Thanks!

**EDIT**: Now I've tried removing the `input` and putting text in (`<label>Hello!</label>`), and it shows up.....so it just doesn't allow inputs wrapped in a `label` element? o.O

Comment: Check your stylesheets. Maybe `label`, `label.item` or `label.item-input` has display property 'none'. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/wLvwlieR01L5r6LN39EX?p=preview) works.

Comment: @IvanMalenko interesting....that code does not work in my app.  I guess I'll just use `ng-if` for the present....but I would like to figure out why that doesn't work.

Comment: can you write sample app like yours, that not work or to show the code of your application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `input` tag.

```
<div ng-repeat="input in input_array">
    <div ng-switch on="input.input_type">
        <div ng-switch-when="text">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Hello World"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```